# Extract Contents of advertisementData[kCBAdvDataManufacturer] in iOS BLE scan in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I would like help extracting the contents of the dictionary:

```
advertisementData[kCBAdvDataManufacturer]
```

`advertisementData` is one of the parameters returned when iOS finds an advertising BLE server during a BLE scan.

I see that it is of type `AnyObject`. When I print it I can see the first character enclosed within <>.

How can I extract the rest of the byte contents?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to cast to String

```
let manufacturerName = advertisementData[kCBAdvDataManufacturer]! as String
println("The manufacturer is \(manufacturerName).")
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
 let manufactureData = ((advertisementData as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "kCBAdvDataManufacturer")) as? String
 print(manufactureData)
```